# R googleway: observe click circle event in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, googleway

How can I catch a circle click event with a googleway map in R Shiny?

Here is my code - based on the [googleway vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/vignettes/googleway-vignette.html) - however the observer doesn't fire.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(googleway)

ui <- fluidPage(
  google_mapOutput(outputId = "map")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  map_key <- ''

  output$map <- renderGoogle_map({

    google_map(key = map_key) %>%
      add_circles(data = tram_stops, id = "stop_id", lat = "stop_lat", lon = "stop_lon"
                   )
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_circle_click, {
    cat(input$map_circle_click$id) # doesn't fire!
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Similar code with polygons works.

Comment: I think there's no `click` event for the circles. There is only `circle_drag` and `circle_edit`.

Comment: Use `map_shape_click` - I think you've found an error in the vignette (and code). The specific click event is [called here](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/lib/circles/circles.js#L122) and [defined here](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/lib/map/map_events.js#L114)

Comment: Look at the tests here: https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/60f1b7198893d524d98c157837d73bb77a4faf18/tests/manual_tests.R#L580

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent my apologies; you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

As per SymbolixAU comment

```
  observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
    cat(input$map_shape_click$id) # this works!
  })
```

I suspect this might change in a future version of googleway :)

Comment: I'll have to make it work with both `_shape_click` and `_circle_click` to avoid any breakages :)

Comment: v2.7.1 of googleway is on its way to CRAN where you can use either `_shape_click` OR `_circle_click`